# Invalid cursor state JSP to Access DB

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%  String qTotal = "SELECT MsThread.ID,MsThread.ThreadName, Count(MsThread.ThreadName) AS TotalPost, ThreadCategory FROM MsThread LEFT OUTER JOIN MsPosts ON MsThread.ThreadName = MsPosts.ThreadName GROUP BY MsThread.ID, MsThread.ThreadName, MsThread.ThreadCategory;";

                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qTotal);
                ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(qTotal);
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    String idThread = rs.getString("id");
                %>                              
                        <tr>
                          <td><img src="f-img/def.png" width="50px" height"50px"/></td>
                          <td><a href="thread.jsp?id=<%=idThread%>"><%=rs.getString("ThreadName")%></a></td>
                          <td><%=rs.getString("TotalPost")%> posts
                          </td>
                          <td>Lala</td>
                        </tr>
                        </div>
                        <br /> <br />            
              <% 
            }
      %>
```

Here's my attempt in connecting a database to a `JSP`, currently showing

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state
this error
```

there i just edited the whole while code. i hope you understand what im trying to show, let me know if more details are needed. 
thanks for the help

Comment: Please post the whole `while` block.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all you are having

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qTotal);
ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(qTotal);
```

why there are two result set that you have not mention as well it looks you didn't write whole while loop.

Your code should be like

```
if(rs != null){
while(rs.next()){
System.out.println(rs.getString('field'));
}
}
```

Comment: if `rs` is `null` it would throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Yes you are right that's why I wrote `it looks you didn't write whole while loop`.

Comment: As well he may try with putting rs.first() before the while loop.

Comment: while(rs.next()){
    String idThread = rs.getString("id");%>        
                      <tr>
                              <td><img src="f-img/def.png" width="50px" height"50px"/></td>
                              <td><a href="thread.jsp?id=<%=idThread%>"><%=rs.getString("ThreadName")%></a></td>
                              <td><%=rs.getString("TotalPost")%> posts
                              </td>
                              <td>Lala</td>
                            </tr>
                      </div>
             <br /> <br />            
              <% 
      }%>

Answer (score 0):

From your code i didn't think any error in it.May be you missing some code in while loop like your ResultSet `rs1` never used in your while loop.

But on the basis of your error i predict below error.

```
There error message Invalid Cursor State indicates that you are trying to access 
the current row's data when in fact the result set is position before the start  
or after the end of the result set.
```

Comment: it seems like the parameter in rs.getString("") is the one having problem, but i just cant figure it out. this is what it looks like on the database side http://s29.postimg.org/6qiv9kc9j/ss_forum.png

Comment: where resultset `rs1` used ?

Comment: i deleted it because i didnt use it. just using resultset rs